# fully web based iphone client-server application?

Tags: iphone, web-services, client-server

I want to create one simple application for sending request from iphone(client) by using http protocol to the server for adding two integer numbers.server process the request and return the response to the client that is my iphone.retrive the result from server and show the result in my iphone.plz giv me a step by step procedure for implement this app.

and also give the detailed explanation for which language is supported for writting the code for implement this application and what are the proticols are used to send the request...

how to retrive the result from server by using which kind of parser like,(xml...)

i'm waiting for ur reply...

Thank u...

Comment: reply me as soon as possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good tutorial on the apple developer site on how to make a http request and receive data [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html).

All app written to the iPhone is done in Objective C using the framework supplied by apple.

The protocol used is http.

If you implement the server part, then you decide what kind of format the result should be. In most cases, depending on the result you want to return, this would be xml. It could also be binary data if it is something like an image.